Memory Leak Issue with Tkinter GUI application
I'm facing a memory leak issue with a custom widget in a Tkinter/customtkinter application. Despite my efforts to manually delete and clear all member variables, the memory is not being fully cleaned up. Below is the relevant code for one of my custom class.
import tkinter
import webbrowser
import customtkinter as ctk
from typing import List, Union, Tuple
from tkinter import PhotoImage
import pyperclip
from utils import (
    ValueConvertUtility,
)
from widgets.components.thumbnail_button import (
    ThumbnailButton,
)
from services import (
    ThemeManager, LanguageManager
)
from settings import (
    AppearanceSettings
)

class Video(ctk.CTkFrame):
    """A class representing a video widget."""

    default_thumbnails: Tuple[tkinter.PhotoImage, tkinter.PhotoImage] = (None, None)

    def __init__(
            self,
            root: ctk.CTk,
            master: Union[ctk.CTkFrame, ctk.CTkScrollableFrame],
            width: int = 0,
            height: int = 0,
            # video info
            video_url: str = "",
            video_title: str = "-------",
            channel: str = "-------",
            thumbnails: List[PhotoImage] = (None, None),
            channel_url: str = "-------",
            length: int = 0):

        super().__init__(
            master=master,
            height=height,
            width=width,
            border_width=1,
            corner_radius=8,
        )
        self.root = root
        self.master = master
        self.height: int = height
        self.width: int = width
        # video details
        self.video_url: str = video_url
        self.video_title: str = video_title
        self.channel: str = channel
        self.channel_url: str = channel_url
        self.length: int = length
        self.thumbnails: List[PhotoImage] = thumbnails
        # widgets
        self.info_frame: Union[ctk.CTkFrame, None] = None
        self.url_label: Union[ctk.CTkLabel, None] = None
        self.video_title_label: Union[ctk.CTkLabel, None] = None
        self.channel_btn: Union[ctk.CTkButton, None] = None
        self.video_length_label: Union[ctk.CTkLabel, None] = None
        self.thumbnail_btn: Union[ThumbnailButton, None] = None
        self.remove_btn: Union[ctk.CTkButton, None] = None

        from widgets import ContextMenu
        self.context_menu: Union['ContextMenu', None] = None
        # initialize the object
        self.create_widgets()
        self.set_widgets_texts()
        self.set_widgets_sizes()
        self.set_widgets_fonts()
        self.set_widgets_colors()
        self.set_tk_widgets_colors()
        self.set_widgets_accent_color()
        self.place_widgets()
        self.bind_widgets_events()

        # register to Theme Manger for accent color updates & widgets colors updates
        ThemeManager.register_widget(self)
        LanguageManager.register_widget(self)

    """
    other methods
    """

    def __del__(self):
        """Clear the Memory."""
        del self.height
        del self.width
        
        # video details
        del self.video_url
        del self.video_title
        del self.channel
        del self.channel_url
        del self.length
        del self.thumbnails

        # widgets
        del self.info_frame
        del self.url_label
        del self.video_title_label
        del self.channel_btn
        del self.video_length_label
        del self.remove_btn

        del self.context_menu
        del self.thumbnail_btn

        del self

    def destroy_widgets(self):
        """Destroy the child widget."""
        self.video_length_label.destroy()
        self.info_frame.destroy()
        self.video_title_label.destroy()
        self.channel_btn.destroy()
        self.url_label.destroy()
        self.remove_btn.destroy()
        self.destroy()

    def kill(self):
        """Destroy the widget."""
        ThemeManager.unregister_widget(self)
        LanguageManager.unregister_widget(self)
        self.pack_forget()
        self.destroy_widgets()
        self.__del__()
        

I am trying to understand why this is not getting cleaned and what is wrong here.
My repository

So you claim to got a memory leak. When? Where? How big? What have you done to measure and to prevent this?

Thank you for your comment.
I added videos to the application, and RAM usage increased accordingly, as observed in the Task Manager. However, when I removed the video object, the RAM usage did not completely return to its previous state. To fix that i wrote destructors for every member variable in the class, but this did not fully resolve the issue.
I open issue in here : https://github.com/Thisal-D/PyTube-Downloader/issues/33

I also had this problem, I created like you a widget inheriting from the CTkFrame and when I destroyed it the RAM usage would not go back to its previous state. I tried solving it but didn't manage to find what was the cause of the leak. I continued adding functionnalities and now it doesn't leak anymore but idk why. Because I had the same problem as you, I can say the problem is probably not coming from the videos but most probably from customtkinter itself.

Hey appreciate the comment.Thanks for information.
